# How can I change the color of this black icon to orange, as shown in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I change this black icon to the same shades and colors as this orange / gold icon?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think most of the answers are overly complicated.

It's been a while since I've used photoshop, but you'll want to pick one of two color adjustment tools. Either 'Colorize' or 'Hue/Saturation'.

Then simply adjust the color and saturation and brightness until you get a match.

No need to redraw anything or use layer masks.

Comment: Yeah...who would not want to have svgs...

Comment: @TroyWoo What do SVGs have to do with this?

Comment: I infer from your words that you focus rather on vector art illustration...

Comment: @TroyWoo the OP is asking about a raster image.

Answer (score 5):

On Photoshop CS5:
1.  Click on the layer with the black graphic 2.  From top menu:  Image > Adjustments > Selective Color.  3.  On Selective Color palette: a.  Preset (drop-down list) > Custom.  b.  Colors (drop-down list) > Black.  4.  Now adjust color sliders.

This works on any black graphic and will colorize it so that the grey feathered edges will be lighter shades of the chosen color, and the black center of the graphic will be a darker shade of the chosen color.  Once the item is colorized, you can further adjust the colors with any other functions from the Image > Adjustments list.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1) Select. Adjustments → Hue

2) In the Layers palette, Layer Style → Color Overlay (you'll have to experiment with the blend modes)

3) Select. Eyedropper the color you want. Option-Delete fills it. (this is crude and may not work for you.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one icon, the fastest way would be to redraw it using shapes.

Draw a circle using the `Ellipse Tool`, and substract a tick shape (I used `Exclude Overlapping Shapes`) using `Custom Shape Tool`. Photoshop comes with one, but it's a bit different from your icon, so you can instead download a shapes pack that has a similar one. [This site has a nice freebie](http://www.shapes4free.com/photoshop-custom-shapes/photoshop-tick-shapes/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is pure black you could use it as a mask.

1. select and copy the layer with the icons.
2. create a new solid color fill layer (any other layer filled with the color you wish will also do fine)
3. Add a layermask to the newly created layer.
4. press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click the layer mask
5. paste the icons into the mask.
6. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to invert the mask.

Condition for this to work is that you have pure black or it won't take the color 100%

//
it just occured to me:
Another way could be to use "Image" > "Match Color..."
You start the command from the image with the black icon and select as Source file and layer with the right colors